# NSFetchedResultsController add Objects manually

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios5, nsfetchrequest

I recently stumbled across a difficult problem..

I'm normally using a `NSFetchedResultsController` to get Data out of my CoreData, and display it within a TableViewController.

The problem I have now is that I can't get the results I want with a NSFetchRequest right away, because having a m:n relationship and I implemented a Table in Core Data (References) which stores the references to the Objects...

So what I do now is, I use a fetch Request:

```
NSArray* references = [self.context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

and then iterate through this array to get my Objects:

```
for(References* ref in references)
{
    Post* tmp = ref.ref_of_post;
}
```

So is there a way to manually add these objects to my `NSFetchedResultsController` or is there a possibility to get the wanted object trough a `NSFetchRequest`?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind that.

I just added these Objects to a `NSMutableArray` and then would use this Array in the same way as the `NSFetchedResultsController`..